# Using offset and limit by in PHP with prepared statements without bind parameter error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble with the following sql query in PHP:

```
$page = 0;
$rows = 10;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT equipment_id, equipment_type, equipment_name FROM equipment_database WHERE equipment_institute_id=? AND equipment_institute_branch_id=? AND equipment_status=? AND CONCAT (equipment_name, equipment_type) LIKE ? ORDER BY equipment_name OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY;");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssii", $institute_id, $institute_branch_id, $active_status, $search_term, $page, $rows);
    $stmt->execute();
```

I am trying to be able to select 10 rows at a time using a previous and next button. This I want to achieve using `OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY` however after running the code I keep getting a fatal error: `atal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in`

I tried variations using `ssssss` instead of `ssssii` and variations of how the query is formulated. Therefore I suspect perhaps a more simple solution I am blind to. Any ideas?

Comment: [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: As far as I know MySQL doesn't have that syntax with `ROWS FETCH NEXT ? ROWS ONLY`

Comment: @Dharman You see, I thought is was something silly from my side. What would the correct syntax be?

Comment: Take a look here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx/

Comment: @Dharman Thanks! Silly mistake but one worth showing to the world for newbies like me!